# Emacs image support

Tags: emacs

I have interest in using the image support in Emacs, as described here http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Images.html

I have Emacs 23.2, but none of the image commands I've tried have been available, including `display-images-p`. (Or I'm trying to run them wrong; I'm using the typical `M-x` thing.)

Any idea what I'm missing? If you get me to point I can run `create-image` I'll be happy.

What's weird is that I DO see the fancy splash screen (with this image http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/powerbook/images/emacs-aa.png) so it does have some measure of support apparently.

Additional info:

- My Emacs was custom-compiled and supposedly configured mostly default. (`./configure --without-sound` basically, plus some stuff for the directory layout here.)
- If you hit "up" a couple times from the manual link I gave above, it says that version of the manual is for 23.2, so I think the versions should match.
- The Linux distro is RHEL 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only commands -- functions which call `(interactive)` -- can be run with <kbd>M-x</kbd>.

All functions (commands or otherwise) can be evaluated in other ways, however. Mickey posted a handy summary recently at his Mastering Emacs blog, so I'll just point you to that:

http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/11/29/evaluating-elisp-emacs/

You could also be missing some image libraries, but when you ran `./configure` before compiling, it would have told you whether or not those libraries were present. If you're unsure, you could repeat that process.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was missing. Thanks.